# How to select rows/ fixes based on a time interval between them in a database with no time pattern?

Tags: r, time, dplyr, subset

I have a database that contains GPS-tracking fixes. It contains 10.000+ fixes/ rows and amongst more variables it  looks something like this:

| UTC_DATETI | UTC_DATE | UTC_TIME | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28/06/2019 9:37 | 28/06/2019 | 9:37:55 | 5,275,832 | 5,740,592 |
| 28/06/2019 9:47 | 28/06/2019 | 9:47:24 | 52,758,362 | 5,740,547 |
| 28/06/2019 10:17 | 28/06/2019 | 10:17:24 | 52,758,366 | 5,740,558 |
| 28/06/2019 10:18 | 28/06/2019 | 10:18:24 | 52,760,109 | 5,739,898 |
| 28/06/2019 11:18 | 28/06/2019 | 11:18:51 | 52,801,404 | 5,786,161 |
| 28/06/2019 11:19 | 28/06/2019 | 11:19:11 | 52,814,363 | 5,765,209 |
| 28/06/2019 11:49 | 28/06/2019 | 11:49:34 | 52,813,770 | 5,766,109 |

`dput` of data

```
structure(list(UTC_DATETI = structure(c(1561689420, 1561690020, 
1561691820, 1561691880, 1561695480, 1561695540, 1561697340), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), UTC_DATE = structure(c(-709130, -709130, 
-709130, -709130, -709130, -709130, -709130), class = "Date"), 
    UTC_TIME = structure(c(34675, 35244, 37044, 37104, 40731, 
    40751, 42574), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    LATITUDE = c(5275832, 52758362, 52758366, 52760109, 52801404, 
    52814363, 52813770), LONGITUDE = c(5740592, 5740547, 5740558, 
    5739898, 5786161, 5765209, 5766109)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(UTC_DATETI = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UTC_DATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UTC_TIME = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_time", 
    "collector")), LATITUDE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), LONGITUDE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

As you can see in the image the intervals between the rows varies a lot (1/ 10 / 30/ 60 minutes), without following any time pattern.
My question would be: how could I select 1 random row from every half an hour in the study period (or more spaced out when that is not possible because of the interval between the rows > 30 minutes)?
I do not want a subset of a specific half an hour but rather one that includes rows with (approximately) half an hour in between them (or more when that is not possible because the interval is >30 min)
Thanks in advance and have a good day!

Ps: hope the "simple" table is enough to grasp the problem and that the format is ok

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You are totally right! Sorry, I edited my question to add a small portion of my dataset in a "copiable" format now

Answer (score 2):

If group the `UTC_DATETI` by every 30 minutes and get the first one of each maybe what you want?

Here is `dput` of your data

```
structure(list(UTC_DATETI = c("28/06/2019 9:37", "28/06/2019 9:47", 
"28/06/2019 10:17", "28/06/2019 10:18", "28/06/2019 11:18", "28/06/2019 11:19", 
"28/06/2019 11:49"), UTC_DATE = c("28/06/2019", "28/06/2019", 
"28/06/2019", "28/06/2019", "28/06/2019", "28/06/2019", "28/06/2019"
), UTC_TIME = structure(c(34675, 35244, 37044, 37104, 40731, 
40751, 42574), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
    LATITUDE = c(5275832, 52758362, 52758366, 52760109, 52801404, 
    52814363, 52813770), LONGITUDE = c(5740592, 5740547, 5740558, 
    5739898, 5786161, 5765209, 5766109)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(UTC_DATETI = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UTC_DATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), UTC_TIME = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_time", 
    "collector")), LATITUDE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), LONGITUDE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Here is the solution using `dplyr`

```r
# One step to convert the UTC_DATETI to POSIXct (datetime format in R)
data$UTC_DATETI <- as.POSIXct(data$UTC_DATETI, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H%M")

data <- data %>%
  mutate(time_group = cut(UTC_DATETI, breaks = "30 min")) %>%
  group_by(time_group) %>%
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = UTC_DATETI)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   time_group [4]
#>   UTC_DATETI          UTC_DATE   UTC_TIME   LATITUDE LONGITUDE time_group       
#>   <dttm>              <date>     <drtn>        <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>            
#> 1 2019-06-28 09:47:00 28-06-20   35244 secs 52758362   5740547 2019-06-28 09:37…
#> 2 2019-06-28 10:18:00 28-06-20   37104 secs 52760109   5739898 2019-06-28 10:07…
#> 3 2019-06-28 11:19:00 28-06-20   40751 secs 52814363   5765209 2019-06-28 11:07…
#> 4 2019-06-28 11:49:00 28-06-20   42574 secs 52813770   5766109 2019-06-28 11:37…
```

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for the help. This seems to totally work out. I knew it had to be something from the dplyr... However, did you do any steps before that? Because I just keep on getting warning messajes and something does not seem to be in place... The messages are as follows:
```

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time_group`.
x Input `time_group` can't be recycled to size 0.
i Input `time_group` is `cut(MHarrier$UTC_DATETI, breaks = "30 min")`.
i Input `time_group` must be size 0 or 1, not 10096.

Comment: I edit the `dput` to have the UTC_DATETI is a character column as similar to your share table - and added one step to convert character into datetime format

Comment: OK, I don't know why I could not change the date format succesfully but goit it now! I do get the desired tibble now! But the thing is the file (in your example "data") does not seem to update and I do not know how to access the tibble (save it/export it), only the first rows are shown in the console (has around 2700 overall) and can't seem to do anything with it... Sorry and thanks for all the time and dedication!

Comment: Just added an assignment to my code to assign the result to the same variable.
`data <- data %>% ...`

Comment: Got it! Could not be more thankful! Have a great one!